# Xamarin Forms crash with async Http call

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await, xamarin-forms-4

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms (4.1.0) app, which makes REST calls.

When calling my web service, the application crashes, with no exception.

Only got this message on the output:

```
07-08 19:09:04.792 F/        (22723): * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-1/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4387, condition `is_ok (error)' not met, function:get_this_async_id, Could not execute the method because the containing type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[RestQueryResultT_REF]', is not fully instantiated. assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
07-08 19:09:04.793 F/libc    (22723): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 22723 (io.puffix), pid 22723 (io.puffix)
```

Here is the code:

```
RestQueryResultT queryResult;

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(serviceUri))
{
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    queryResult = ParseResult(result);
}

return queryResult;
```

The call is made from an event handler method, fired by a UI action.
The GetAsync call made tha app crashes.

Any idea to solve this issue ?

Comment: which line causes the crash?  Have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: The GetAsync line cause the crash. Yes, tried to add catch, and suscribed to errors from the App, with no success.

Comment: does it only crash on Android?  Have you tried switching the HTTP stack?  Do you have Internet permissions enabled?  Have you tested that your url is accesible from the device/emulator using the browser?

Comment: I am developping only on Android. The internet permissions are enabled. The URL is browsable from my device. How can I switch the HTTP Stack ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows

Comment: and try a different device/emulator to verify it's not a device issue

Comment: I checked the HTTP stack, it was correct. I put the GetAsync call outside the using, and it is working no. Should it be this ? However, thank you for your help and your time  @Jason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems a issue and already filed in the `Github`. You can see the discussions in these threads:

1. [await within method with returntype Task makes app crash](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4380)
2. [xamarin-android/issues](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1472)
3. [xamarin-ios/issues](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4380)

The workaround is using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `await`:

**Works:**

```
response = _client.GetAsync(uri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

**Does not work:**

```
await _client.GetAsync(uri);
```

Comment: Thanks... This is pathetic !  The problem has been there for a long time and not fixed yet !

Comment: this helped me too - been scratching my head at this for awhile. how is this still an issue?!

Answer (score 1):

could you try with a smaller response? I had the same problem (in my case, when I tested with 2 or 3 records from the server, it worked fine, but if I used 10 records, it crashed). I had to change the simulator. I am using now my real phone connected to my computer.