# Call http with larger json error in the emulator

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, task, polly

When I make this same call through the emulator, passing as a parameter a higher limit, consequently the json will be higher, this error is shown, but if the limit is lower and the json smaller, it does not show the error.

And by my physical cell phone the error is not disassembling at any time

> Error: not met, function:get_this_async_id, Could not execute the method because the containing type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[TResult_REF]', is not fully instantiated. assembly: type: member:(null)

I'm using the polly library to make http calls

my code

```cs
public async Task<Hero> GetHeroesWichFactory(string limite)
{
    var func = new Func<Task<Hero>>(() => HeroGetRequest(limite));

     //main function
    return await _networkService.WaitAndRetry<Hero>(func, new Func<int,
        TimeSpan>(time => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, time))), 3);
}

async Task<Hero> HeroGetRequest(string limite)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetUrl(limite));

    var rawResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hero>(rawResponse);
}

public async Task<T> WaitAndRetry<T>(Func<Task<T>> func, Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, int retryCount)
{
    return await WaitAndRetryInner<T>(func, sleepDurationProvider, retryCount);
}

internal async Task<T> WaitAndRetryInner<T>(Func<Task<T>> func, Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, int retryCount = 1, Func<Exception, TimeSpan, Task> onRetryAsync = null)
{
    var onRetryInner = new Func<Exception, TimeSpan, Task>((e, t) =>
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Retrying in {t.ToString("g")} due to exception '{(e.InnerException ?? e).Message}'");
        });
    });

    return await Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount, sleepDurationProvider, onRetryAsync ?? onRetryInner).ExecuteAsync<T>(func);
}
```

note: sometimes the error stops happening in the emulator, and suddenly comes back, without having had any changes in the code

accept code suggestion please, this is the repository https://github.com/gabriel-projetos/AppMarvel

Comment: [You're not the first to encounter this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939778/xamarin-forms-crash-with-async-http-call), though given the age of the previous question I'm not sure how relevant the answer is now.

Comment: worse I have tried some "solutions" but it seems that nothing works with full certainty of success. eventually the same error happens, there doesn't seem to be a pattern, because sometimes it doesn't give the error and sometimes it does, without having had any changes in the code

Comment: If you want a dumb idea, you could create a WebView and do all your web requests through it instead.

Comment: at what limit does the error occur?  how large is the json payload at that point?